# div-ссылка HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Я имею данный код:

```html
<div class="swiper-slide showcase-carousel__item">
   <div class="showcase-carousel__image-wrapper">
      <div class="showcase-carousel__image-left">
         <div class="showcase-carousel__image" style="background-image: url(images/1.png);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="showcase-carousel__image-right">
         <div class="showcase-carousel__image" style="background-image: url(images/1.png);"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p>VK</p>
</div>
```

И у меня возникает вопрос, как мне сделать картинку (div) так-же ссылкой на сторонний ресурс?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: оберните `div` в `a`, а лучше чтобы внутри `a` не было блочных элементов. лучше из заменить на `span` а поведение определить на `css`

Comment: по правилам HTML нельзя оборачивать div в a

Comment: @legend.developer, при этом много где это используется.

Comment: @legend.developer поэтому я написал про `span` и `css`

Comment: @legend.developer ничего подобного нет в актуальной спецификации, вы можете оборачивать в ссылки что угодно, кроме других ссылок и [интерактивного контента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82). Документ останется валидным, не говоря уж о том, что на практике это всегда нормально работало в браузерах.

Comment: Замените `div` на `a` и подправьте стили так, чтоб визуально ссылка выволилась как первоначальный `div`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать атрибут [`onclick`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onclick) и в качестве значения указать `window.location={url}` — где `window.location` — то, что будет в окне после нажатия на div, и `{url}` — сама страница для перехода (в том числе на сторонние сайты).

```html
<div class="showcase-carousel__image" style="background-image: url(images/1.png); onclick="window.location='http://google.com';"></div>
```

Comment: только это не ссылка, а типа ссылка - поисковики проигнорируют подобные "ссылки"